# Insert copied row based on cell value

Tags: excel, insert, copy, vba

The vba code below (modified from [here](http://www.excelforum.com/excel-general/846209-excel-2007-a-macro-to-insert-an-empty-row-based-on-specified-criteria.html)) will insert a blank row above any row that has a value of "0" in column E.  Instead of inserting a blank row, is there a way to copy the row with "0" and insert it above itself?  Can this vba code be modified to do this?

```
Sub BlankLine()

    Dim Col As Variant
    Dim BlankRows As Long
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim R As Long
    Dim StartRow As Long

        Col = "E"
        StartRow = 1
        BlankRows = 1

            LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, Col).End(xlUp).Row

            Application.ScreenUpdating = False

            With ActiveSheet
For R = LastRow To StartRow + 1 Step -1
If .Cells(R, Col) = "0" Then
.Cells(R, Col).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown
End If
Next R
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Insert the copied row above *what*?  In any case, yes, this can be done and it should be fairly easy. Have you tried using the macro recorder while manually performing the copy/insertion?  This will generate some code that you may be able to use to modify this macro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add this line

```
.Cells(R, Col).EntireRow.Copy
```

before your `.Insert` line