# Insert row below based on cell value

Tags: excel, vba

I found a macro at [Insert copied row based on cell value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16513654/insert-copied-row-based-on-cell-value-excel-2007-macro).

The macro inserts a blank row above any row that has a value of "0" in column E.

Instead of the empty row appearing above, I need it to appear below.

```
Sub BlankLine()

    Dim Col As Variant
    Dim BlankRows As Long
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim R As Long
    Dim StartRow As Long

    Col = "E"
    StartRow = 1
    BlankRows = 1

    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, Col).End(xlUp).Row

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    With ActiveSheet
        For R = LastRow To StartRow + 1 Step -1
            If .Cells(R, Col) = "0" Then
                .Cells(R, Col).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown
            End If
        Next R
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 4):

Edit the following line from:

```
.Cells(R, Col).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown
```

to:

```
.Cells(R+1, Col).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown
```

Answer (score 1):

Pertinent to you question, modify a single line in original code: instead of:

```
.Cells(R, Col).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown
```

use this one:

```
.Cells(R, Col).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlUp
```

Rgds,