# Insert row xlUP not working

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I found the code below over here: [Insert row below based on cell value excel macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24489376/insert-row-below-based-on-cell-value-excel-macro)

It works but, like the poster in the other message, I want the new row to be inserted below the existing row (here the row with a "2" in it), rather than above.  I've tried changing `Shift:=xlDown` to `xlUp` but that has no effect.  What am I missing something?

```
Sub BlankLine()

    Dim Col As Variant
    Dim BlankRows As Long
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim R As Long
    Dim StartRow As Long

        Col = "C"
        StartRow = 1
        BlankRows = 1

            With ActiveSheet
For R = LastUsedRow() To StartRow + 1 Step -1

If .Cells(R, Col) = "2" Then

.Cells(R, Col).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown 

End If
Next R
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To insert the row below `R` use `R + 1`. Is this what you are trying?

```
Dim R As Long, LastRow As Long

LastRow = LastUsedRow()

With ActiveSheet
    For R = LastRow To 2 Step -1
        If .Range("C" & R).Value = 2 Then _
        .Range("C" & R + 1).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Next R
End With
```