# macro inserting new row at the bottom disables data validation

Tags: excel, vba, insert

[image: Image Please See Me]

Sub InsertRow()
    Dim rActive As Range

```
Set rActive = ActiveCell

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)
.EntireRow.Copy
With .Offset(1, 0).EntireRow
.PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
On Error Resume Next
.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).ClearContents
On Error GoTo 0
End With
End With
rActive.Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

My problem is, when my file is shared with others (share workbook), myself and them can save and everything and add rows, but the thing is the data validation  is not copied in the new line and the drop down won't appear.

Anyone can help?

Comment: If you insert a new row directly below the last row the data validation should extend, although when I copy and paste I also retain the validation. Is the problem post sharing or occurs even before hand?

Comment: My teacher wanted to have an insert button, so that she won't just copy paste, she likes one click, so I have to make a macro.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Your code worked for me so it looks like it might be something related to sharing (as per my comment).

```
Sub InsertRow()

Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove

End Sub
```

Comment: Good.. This code works but the border didn't copy in the row. Thanks @CaptainGrumpy

Comment: Formulas won't copy as well

Comment: Good point, guess I was focused on the data validation. Looks like it is an issue with the sharing. Do you have to have sharing or can you have the file stored in a group accessible location (like a network drive)? If you have to have the sharing and no one comes up with anything else, if there are only a couple of formula the maybe set them in the code else I will have another think about it. Oh, have you tried using a table (you can format them and the formula should carry down when inserting).

Comment: It's okay now Captain Grumpy. The code now is good.. It runs perfectly with your code. Thanks a lot

Comment: Ahhh ok, you inserted to retain the data validation and then copied the formula etc as before. Clever workaround.

Comment: Hi Captain Grumpy, I've got another question. I found this thread(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24489376/insert-row-below-based-on-cell-value-excel-macro), I wanted to insert a row that has a specific cell value, and I want to copy the format and data validations of the its above cell. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

With this code of @Captain Grum

```
Sub InsertRow()

Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove

End Sub
```

It copies now the data validation below, but the borders and formula won't copy.

[Please see this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O39R4.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I'm really sorry guys. I'm really just new to programming. I now have the solution to my problems. I just have included the code of @captain grumpy and mine above. Here's the code:

```
    Sub InsertRow()
Dim rActive As Range

Set rActive = ActiveCell

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

With Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)
    .Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    .EntireRow.Copy
    With .Offset(1, 0).EntireRow
        .PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
        On Error Resume Next
            .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).ClearContents
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With

End With



rActive.Select

Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```